# django cant create tables

Tags: django, django-models

i tried to figure out why  i have a problem in my code and after insulation i figured that django cant create tables for 2 of my models for some reason

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import models
import misaka
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

    class Race(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    attack = models.IntegerField()
    deffence = models.IntegerField()
    intelligence = models.IntegerField()
    agility = models.IntegerField()
    wisdom = models.IntegerField()
    charisma = models.IntegerField()

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("characters:race_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    attack = models.IntegerField()
    deffence = models.IntegerField()
    intelligence = models.IntegerField()
    agility = models.IntegerField()
    wisdom = models.IntegerField()
    charisma = models.IntegerField()


    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("characters:role_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here is the traceback which provide the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: characters_race

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>

    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 368, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: characters_race
```

when i browse the database i saw that every tabel is named appName_modelName so from that you can tell that the problem is in creating the table.
and in the migration folder under the app there is no other file besides `__init__.py`

Answer (score 1):

Please Post also your Imports.

My common mistakes when Django can´t find new Tables or Migrations.

1. forgot to install the app
2. missing `__init__.py` in Migrations

   `yourApp/migrations/__init__.py`

Comment: I installed all of my imports and __init__.py is in my migrations folder

Comment: Does the Server print any Info? try `python manage.py makemigrations <App_Name>`. And provide more info in your question , file name, your imports (from django.db import models`) etc.